# Adding comments to endpoints w/ Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, api, swagger

I'm using Swagger / Swashbuckle for my API. I want the Swagger UI to show the method descriptions. In their [documents](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments) it says:

---

2 - Configure Swashbuckle to incorporate the XML comments on file into the generated Swagger JSON:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
        new Info
        {
            Title = "My API - V1",
            Version = "v1"
        }
     );

     var filePath = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "MyApi.xml");
     c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
}
```

---

Can someone please explain this?  What I am supposed to do with this code? Do I copy and paste it somewhere? If so, where?

(.NET Framework 4.7)

**EDIT:**

The answer by Jawad below led me to the solution. In the original SwaggerConfig.cs file, there was this:

```
// If you annotate Controllers and API Types with
// Xml comments (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7(v=vs.110).aspx), you can incorporate
// those comments into the generated docs and UI. You can enable this by providing the path to one or
// more Xml comment files.
//
//c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
```

I was unclear on how to change that last line to add my XML file.  This worked:

```
c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "bin\\KGC.API.xml"));
```

I also had to add `using System.IO`.

Comment: do you have a SwaggerConfig.cs file under App_Start ?

Comment: Yes. I've been looking at that and trying to figure out where/how to add this code to it

Comment: http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/ -> Use this for other aspects of your configuraiton as well :)

Comment: Looks like this code would go in Startup in the ConfigureServices method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way i have done it is by updating the SwaggerConfig.cs file ..

```
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger("docs/{apiVersion}", c =>
            {
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Title Of API");
                c.Schemes(new List<string> { "http", "https" });
                c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
                c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "MyApi.xml"));
            });
    }
```

Last line in the code above enabled the XML comment tagging.

One other thing you have to do is,

1. Go to Properties of Project (not Solution)
2. Build / Output -> Add path to XML Documentation File.

For Reference Purposes, [this](http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/) was quite helpful.